# How to close session in Fragment from click event that occurs in Activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-lifecycle

I've inherited a video playing app that I need to add analytics to. In my fragment I create the analytics object and this object then listens to and reports events and data. If the user clicks on another item in the parent activity's recycler view, I need to be able to trigger the current fragment's session to end.

I have tried creating an instance of the fragment in my activity and calling the method from the click event but the method never gets called and the session continues:

```
VideoFragment videoFragment = new VideoFragment();
videoFragment.endSession();
```

How can I end this session in my fragment from my activity?

UPDATE: I've also tried this in the parent activity, but the app crashes.

```
FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
VideoFragment videoFrag = (VideoFragment) fm.findFragmentByTag("VideoFragment");
if (videoFrag != null) {
    videoFrag.endSession();
            }
```

Comment: Is the session the analytics session of that fragment? And when the user clicks on something else does that close the current fragment?

Comment: @ryankuck Yes, the session is the analytics session of the fragment that is playing. When a user clicks another video that fragment is replaced by a new fragment and the session needs to be closed and a new session starts for the next video playing.

Answer (score 0):

The fragment can manage it's own analytics based on it's own lifecycle. In onResume() of the fragment:

```
// Initialized and start the analytics
startSession()
```

In onPause():

```
// Stop the session and remove reference to it
endSession();
```

Comment: My fragment isn't being destroyed in this situation, just replaced with another fragment when a different video is clicked. So onDestroy() is not called.

Comment: Hmm, I updated my answer to onPause, onResume then if that works